# How to compute hitting probability for this Markov chain?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let the homogeneous Markov chain $\left(X_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be described by the following graph:

> [image]

Then the only missing arrow is from $0$ to $0$ with $\mathbb P\left(X_{1}=0 | X_{0}=0\right)= 1-3/5-1/5 = 1/5$.

I would like to compute $h_0^6$, the probability of starting from $0$ and hitting $6$. Let $h_i$ be the the probability of starting from $i$ and hitting $6$. From the diagram, we have $h_1=h_2=h_3 =0$ because $\{1,2,3\}$ is a closed class. Then I have the following system of equations:

$$\begin{aligned}
h_0 &= \sum_{i=0}^6 p_{0,i} h_i &&= \frac{1}{5} h_0  + \frac{1}{5} h_4\\
h_4 &= \sum_{i=0}^6 p_{4,i} h_i &&= 1h_5\\
h_5 &= \sum_{i=0}^6 p_{5,i} h_i &&= 1h_6\\
h_6 &= \sum_{i=0}^6 p_{6,i} h_i &&= 1h_4
\end{aligned}$$

It follows that $4 h_0 = h_4 =h_5 =h_6$.

---

After that, I'm stuck. Could you please shed me some light to finish this exercise? Thank you so much!

Comment: You start at 0. One of three things can happen: you stay at 0, you leave towards {1,2,3} and will never hit 6, or you leave towards {4,5,6} and are certain to hit 6, because the {4,5,6} subgraph is a directed cycle which is at each step "certain". So your problem is only concentrated on the first step: you'll hit 6 so long as you don't go left towards {1,2,3}. Does that give you better ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

You missed using the fact that $h_6 = 1$ (we will reach 6 for sure as we are starting at 6). Once we use that, we get $h_0 = \frac{1}{4}, h_4 = h_5 = h_6 = 1$.

Comment: Could you please explain how $h_6 = 1$ from the definition of hitting time?

Comment: So $h_i^i = 1$ for all $i$, right?

Comment: Yes. We are starting there implies we already hit that state.